# Error Loading Simple XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml document (generated from msword 2010), which I am trying to process using simple xml.

Sample of xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
<w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidR="005B1098" w:rsidRDefault="005B1098"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00F254A4" w:rsidRDefault="00F254A4"/>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00F254A4" w:rsidRPr="008475A1" w:rsidRDefault="00C15492" w:rsidP="008475A1">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:sz w:val="44"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="44"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="008475A1">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:b/>
                <w:sz w:val="44"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="44"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>Test file</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00C15492" w:rsidRPr="008475A1" w:rsidRDefault="00C15492" w:rsidP="008475A1">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="008475A1">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>another paragraph</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

I am trying to open it using:

```
$content = '/reports/docx_templates/testing2.xml';
if(!$simple_xml = simplexml_load_file($content)){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
} else {
    echo 'loaded';
}
```

And get the error:

```
Message: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity " Test file another paragraph "
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `$content` ? a file ?

Comment: Have you run the XML through a validator? [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: put @ in the beginning of `simplexml_load_file($content)`

Comment: $content is the file, it exists and the permissions are 0777

Comment: @Rooneyl can you add the code where you set $content - im guessing you are not escaping the slashes correctly

Comment: @cillosis, it validated with only one warning -  No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

Comment: Try using the absolute full path to rule out any relative path problems.

Comment: @webbandit that will only surpress the error ! waste of time !

Comment: @ManseUK, have added code. Also MrCode, have tried that

Comment: You need a ; too. But that's not the problem.

Comment: @Rooneyl you realise `/reports` is in the root of the server, not the document/htdocs root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the SimpleXMLElement Class.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($content));
```

I have test it with your XML file and its working.

**Edit:**

here is a short tutorial to parse a word XML file: [Word XML](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/9d2f43d0-0e94-47e1-990e-0bea9ba780b1/)

Comment: Can you please post what you did, I have tried your solution and it is still failing

Comment: I've tried this and also the other way and I keep getting an empty object. I think it's something to do with the XML. Could it be a namespace issue?

Comment: Check the Site that i have added. You have to register the namespace and access the elements over XPATH. And you should think about that its possible that he go directly to the document element.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something going on with PHP's XML parser that's not quite right.

http://schemas.openxmlformats.org does not go to a valid web address.... but it doesn't have to because the XML namespace rules don't insist on it. However, look at this page

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60416

and you see that someone has managed to workaround your problem with a kludge on the namespace.

I'm suspecting that what your original question shows might be successful running of the code but with an error message that you forced by using trigger_error.

This is too long for a comment.

And it's not really an answer, so here's a suggestion to make up for it...

Run this code after saving your xml as testing2.xml in the same directory as the php file.

```
<?php

if (file_exists('testing2.xml')) {
    $content = file_get_contents('testing2.xml');
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content );
    echo "<pre>";        
    var_dump($xml );
    echo "</pre>"; 
} else {
    exit('Failed to open testing2.xml.');
}
```